# Can I delete the .pom and .lastUpdated files in maven's .m2 repository?

Tags: maven

I have some .pom and .lastUpdated files in my local .m2 repository.. Can I delete them?

I need to put the .m2 folder on a server, where downloading won't be possible for the jars.

I tried putting true in settings.xml of MAVEN_HOME/conf but to no avail. Maven still tries to downloads a few jars (has been failing everytime).

The reason for this unauthorized download I believe is the existence of .pom and .lastUpdated files in repository. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in your .m2/repository directory;

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set [offline to true in your settings xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)?

If this is now working, is because you have the settings.xml in the wrong place. Maven does respect this property.

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <!-- also point here to the repository that you'll copy from another computer -->
  <offline>true</offline>
</settings>
```

```sh
# mvn clean install
[INFO]
NOTE: Maven is executing in offline mode. Any artifacts not already in your local
```

Comment: Am using Hudson to build my code from SVN. And the MAVEN_HOME in Hudson is set to my desired place. How else can I make sure if that's the right place?

Comment: the settings xml should be in $HOME/.m2, please read the maven documentation I linked in the answer.

Comment: I had read that...and have cross-checked my settings.xml location too. That's crazy..

Answer (score 0):

Other solution could be to remove your repositories from the pom.xml and install directly from your server.
For this you need to install your jars with the instruction `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=YOURJAR.jar -DgroupId=GROUPID_OF_YOU_JAR -DartifactId=ARTIFACID_OF_YOU_JAR -Dversion=VERSION -Dpackaging=jar`, put it, for example in the same folder thar your pom.xml

Comment: I cannot do that, cos on my local when i run with the -o command it works fine. Any other suggestion please?

Comment: note that this would be a *lot* of work if you have say 100+ dependencies, which also have dependencies..

Comment: @Swat that's not a reason why you couldn't do that (I don't see how that's related even)

Comment: We had hudson on a server before that was working fine without any change of code. Somehow, the whole setup was lost and am now re-configuring....the first time was configured by some other person whom I cannot contact now. I hope you see a point now.

Comment: No, still don't see a point. There's nothing preventing you to do mvn install:install-file, and the fact that local run with -o command works fine is unrelated. However, I wouldn't do that as it is a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically no, you're not correct, that's not the reason. The reason is that your repo has dependencies that are not located in that repo, or they have snapshot dependencies and you've instruct to update the snapshot dependencies.

The fix is to

- first issue a command `mvn dependency:go-offline` to get offline versions of all your dependency artifacts and plugins
- then copy the repository folder you have to your server in the maven repository folder
- then specify offline flag (`-o`) to all your server runs or use maven settings to set offline to true (preferred), like was already proposed in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314396/365237)

Comment: Eis.. am using Hudson to build my code and that in turn uses the MAVEN_HOME located on my server. That's why am unable to implement your 'command' suggestion. I think there's something with the Hudson UI and Maven's settings.xml

Comment: @Swat how is that preventing you to use commands? With hudson, you just specify it in the maven configuration? I've never had any problems specifying them in Hudson.